# How do I download a single directory from android.googlesource.com or github.com?

Tags: git, github

I want to download either:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/tools/aapt/

or

https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/master/tools/aapt

Comment: Do you need to download this directory yourself, just once, or automatically in a program?

Comment: Just once for myself.

Answer (score 26):

As of today, *android.googlesource.com* has a link [tgz] on each directory page, it is in small font, but it works:

[image: the [tgz] link works!]

You cannot download a separate file, but you can download a directory.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't find this link by myself and had to come to SO for help! Still working in 2018, thanks. ;-)

Comment: Actually is possible to download a file directly, more info here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72876327/what-is-the-official-android-repository-containing-apksigner/76419232#76419232

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can download single file in base64 text format:

```sh
curl https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/master/tools/aapt?format=text | base64 -d
```

Answer (score 3):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13738951/578288) looks like it will work. It tells you how to make a [sparse checkout](http://schacon.github.io/git/git-read-tree.html#_sparse_checkout) using Git. Make sure you have Git 1.7.0 or later installed, then run this:

```sh
git init platform_frameworks_base-aapt
cd platform_frameworks_base-aapt
git remote add -f origin https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base.git
git config core.sparsecheckout true
echo tools/aapt/ >> .git/info/sparse-checkout
git pull origin master
```

Comment: `git remote add -f origin https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base.git` uses an unacceptable amount of bandwidth, but thank you for this method when only git access is available. `svn export` as detailed below provides a great method specific to **github.com**.

Comment: You’re right, this does download the whole repository. I tried leaving out the `-f` (“fetch”) flag on the [`git remote add`](http://schacon.github.io/git/git-remote.html), but Git still fetches the whole repo later, at the `git pull`. I looked at some more SO questions, but it looks like Git doesn’t support what you want.

Answer (score 3):

If you have `svn`, you can do this:

```
svn export https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/trunk/tools/aapt
```

It will create the `aapt` directory locally, without any version control files in it.

Comment: Thank you for this simple solution.